# How to log every event that is sent to Puppeteer/Chrome dev toops

Tags: puppeteer

Is there a way to log every event that is sent to Puppeteer via Chrome Dev Protocol?

eg:

```
await page.click("button");
```

would log:

```
"Page.click","button"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer uses the [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) NPM module.

If you add the env variable `"DEBUG":"puppeteer:protocol"`, you would get all the messages sent and received to/from Chromium.

That output will be extremely raw, so you might need to do some cooking there.